# codeignaiter 404 - File or directory not found. on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I'm working on php Codeigniter project.** 
after testing offline it was working fine, when i uploaded it to live server only home page working and i think it's working from `$route['default_controller'] = "home";` but i have tried to access any of my controllers even home controller. i have made all my controllers' first letters upper case letters, and it didn't working too. and i always got ## 404 - File or directory not found ## , when i call any controller.

[image: 404 - not found]

Answer (score 0):

Your controller name and the class name must be same and first letter should be uppercase  and rest of the letter should be lowercase

Comment: i have made all my controllers' first letters upper case letters